# Fix 'SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items' without modifying SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsUsers" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csDB1 %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT UserID, UserName, RoleID
                    FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Users]
                    ORDER BY UserName">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsRoles" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csDB2 %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT RoleID, RoleName
                    FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Roles]
                    WHERE RoleActive = 1">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UserID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="dsUsers">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="UserName" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddRole" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RoleID") %>' DataSourceID="dsRoles" DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="RoleID"  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
          <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The `Users` table and the `Roles` table are in separate databases using separate connection strings, I cannot change this. I have been told not to perform any JOINS between these tables/databases.

This code throws the following error:

> 'ddRole' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

I know why the error is happening.  There is a User who has a RoleID and the Role has been disabled in the Roles table (RoleActive is 0).  This doesn't happen often but it does sometimes happen.  I can fix this with a SQL script to either reactive the Role or changing the users RoleID to a valid role.  However I am looking for a solution that will not cause an error to show up on the webpage.  Ideally what I'd like to see is if the value doesn't exist in the dsRoles record then the DropDownList should show the "-Select=" item that was added.  However I have been unsure how to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just make the `-Select-` value 0?

Comment: You could try doing this in the `GridView RowDataBound` and check the RoleID column in the rowdata against the Roles table - by making a query against it (not very efficient I admit!) and if the RoleID is not found set it to '0'. You could remove your `Bind` there and assign it manually in the RowDataBound.

That might work. Or an option is to disable the ones which are not active so they can't be selected by the user which also might require a javascript control.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind when you bind the dropdown, wrap the selectedvalue call in a try catch, that way you can explicitly set the selectedValue should an error get thrown. e.g.

```
 dropdown.DataSource = dsUsers;
 dropdown.DataBind();

 try
 {
     dropdown.SelectedValue = yourvalue;
 }
 catch()
 {
    // set it to blank (-select one-) which is valid as its appended from databounditems
    dropdown.SelectedValue = "";
 }
```